# Carousel bootstrap does not work in IE 10

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the carousel bootstrap but does not work correctly in Internet Explorer 10. In Mozilla and Chrome it works perfectly.

Here is my code in index.php:

```
<div id="this-carousel-id" class="carousel slide" style="width: 90%;">
        <div class="carousel-inner" style="width: 100%;">
          <div class="item active" style="width: 100%;">
            <img style="width: 100%; height: 350px;" src="img/bg_home_1.JPG"/>
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <p>O que extraimos</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="item" style="width: 100%;">
              <img src="img/bg_home_2.jpg"  style="width: 100%; height: 350px;"/>
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <p>Temos uma basta variedade de produtos</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="item" style="width: 100%;">
              <img src="img/bg_home_3.jpg" style="width: 100%; height: 350px;"/>
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <p>Estamos equipados com o melhor material</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div><!-- .carousel-inner -->
        <!--  next and previous controls here
              href values must reference the id for this carousel -->
        <a class="carousel-control left" href="#this-carousel-id" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
          <a class="carousel-control right" href="#this-carousel-id" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
      </div>
```

(....)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#carousel').carousel({
      interval: 4000
    });
  });
</script>
```

You can see the result online at:
http://graniextracao.com/novosite/.

Comment: IE10's console is complaining about your use of `</br>`: `Invalid end tag: "</br>". Use "<br>" or "<br/>" instead.` Almost certainly not the problem, but you might want to sort it out anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

You have included two jQuery's remove one

```
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="lightbox/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you remove jquery 1.7.2 from http://graniextracao.com/novosite/ so we can test that theory?

Comment: OK. Your bootstrap code is rather old, too. Have you tried updating to [Bootstrap 2.3.2](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/) or even [Bootstrap 3.0.0](http://getbootstrap.com/) to see if they fixed the issue?